# No Handler Found - Java 11 issue?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, java-11

I just moved to Java 11 and Spring 5 and Tomcat 9.  I'm setting up a simple HelloWorld program in spring-mvc with code that works fine if I set the compiler compliance level to 1.8. However using 11 I am getting a status 404 error showing:

```
Mar 29, 2019 11:20:52 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /spring-mvc-demo/showForm
```

Here is what I want my app to do.  When I run on Tomcat it takes me to my "main-menu.jsp" page and the url in the browser is: `http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-demo/`
I want to be able to add /showForm to that url in the browser and see "helloworld-form.jsp".  When I add /showForm to the url however, I get the no handler found 404 error.

Here is my code starting with Controller classes:

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    // need a controller method to show the initial HTML form

    @RequestMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm() {
        return "helloworld-form";
    }

}

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showPage() {
        return "main-menu";
    }
}
```

Here are my configuration files:
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>
    <absolute-ordering></absolute-ordering>
    <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo" />

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Thanks in advance for your help - I truly appreciate it.
Constantine

Comment: is the controller in the package "com.luv2code.springdemo"? That's the package you have Spring scan for controllers.

Comment: Yes.  The interesting thing is that it works if I change the compliance level to 1.8.  I change it to 1.8 and it works for a couple runs and then I get 404 again.  So I switch it back to 11 and then, surprisingly, it works.  It seems that its not the compliance level so much as something else that happens when I switch levels.  I've tried rebuilding the project and then running but the sporadic problem persists.

Comment: It might be the Spring version you are running. From what I remember only Spring 5.1 or Spring Boot 2.1 support Java 11. It might be easier to get a a fully bootstrapped project at Spring.io -> Spring Boot, rather that trying to upgrade a Java 8 / Spring 4.3 project.

Comment: @Constantine Can give a screenshot of your project structure ?